# PHP Simple HTML Dom Memory Issue

Tags: php, dom, parsing

I'm running into memory issues with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.  I'm parsing a fair sized doc and need to run down the DOM tree...

1)I'm starting with the whole file:

```
$html = file_get_html($file);
```

2)then parsing out my table:

```
$table = $html->find('table.big');
```

3)then parsing out my rows:

```
$rows = $table[0]->find('tr');
```

What I'm ending up with are three GIANT objects... anyone know how to dump an object after I've parsed it for the data I need?  Like $html is useless by step 3, yet, it's the largest of all the objects.

Any ideas?

Is there a way to drill down to my table rows out of the original $html object?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I've managed to skip step two with:

```
$rows = $this->html->find('table.big tr');
```

But am still running into memory issues...

Comment: As mentioned by Aakash Sahai you have to use clear(). Without it my script would use around 140MB of ram, with it only 1.3MB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory is really a big concern, you may want to look into [SAX](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) instead of using DOM. You may want to try `unset()` on the `$html` after obtaining `$table`, but that is simply just marking it to be garbage collected and memory **won't be freed up immediately**.

At the end of the day, it is really up to how memory-efficient Simple HTML DOM is written or which implementation you have chosen.

Answer (score 23):

I may be little late...to answer as i joined late...so the answers given above are not correct. unset only unsets the $html not its properties. So to clean up memory and kick off the memory issue is :

use `$html->clear();`.

I think u didint read the class code before using it. clear() function destroy/release the memory eaten up by the $html object.This function is internal function of simple_html_dom.This function immediately take effect. So u dont have to wait whole day or program termination to take effect.

Comment: As mentioned here in the docs http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm

Comment: Saved my life (literately :D)

Comment: saved me from 900MB to 6MB :o

Comment: simple_html_dom should handle this problem internally :/

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the memory limit.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

or clear the memory with this code

```
$html->__destruct();
unset($html);
$html = null;
```

Comment: In your example, `$html->__destruct()` would throw an error since `$html` isn't an object anymore.

Comment: @Crontab you can use any of them.

Comment: My comment had to do with the order you had things; you had the call to `$html->__destruct()` **after** you did `unset($html);`.  That was wrong.  You have since changed it.  The easiest method would be to just call `$html->clear();` as that method was written by the class developer to handle this exact issue (as mentioned in the developer's own community).

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to dump an object after I've
>   parsed it for the data I need? Like
>   $html...

`unset($html)` ?

or `$html = null;` might work better - more of an immediate affect?