# simple_html_dom.php memory problems

Tags: php

I am trying to write a crawler using simple_html_dom.php version 1.5 but it seems it leaks memory for reasons unknown. I tried the 1.5 because they claim to have fixed memory leaks help will be appreciated.
after 40 repetitions of the loop i get the following message

```
   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in C:\work\simple_html_dom.php on line 1078
<?php
/**
* ******************TESTING*************************
*/




include("simple_html_dom.php");


$beginning=0;
$end=35;
$FileName = "c:/results.txt";
$FileHandle = fopen($FileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");

for ($i = $beginning; $i < $end; $i++) {

$url = sprintf('http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/day/page/%d?scrolled',$i);

$html = file_get_html($url);

echo "Day: -".$i."\n";


foreach($html -> find('div[class=posts]') as $element){




    foreach($element -> find('img') as $el)
    {
        $urls = $el-> src;
        $urls1 = str_replace('b.jpg','.jpg',$el->src);
        $urls2 =     str_replace('.jpg','',str_replace('.com/','.com/gallery/',str_replace('http://i.','http://',str_replace('b.jpg','.jpg',$el->src))));

        $title=str_replace('&quot;','"',str_replace('&#039;',"'",stristr($el-> title,'<p>',true)));
        $fil= $urls2.'             '.$urls.'             '.$urls1.'             '.$title."\n";
        fwrite($FileHandle, $fil);

    }
}

$html->clear;
unset($html);
}

fclose($FileHandle);




?>
```

Comment: If you indent your code, it would be easier to read.

Comment: Try to do a unset($element); just after the inner foreach.

Comment: I would consider that simple_html_dom is an outdated library that has a broken design. You should replace it with something better, there are other, better libraries available.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: Thanks i will try them in other projects but since this just a part of the whole it would take some time to change the entire code to use the other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$html->clear;
```

if this is your actual code then you may want to change it to function call: `$html->clear();`

If its not the issue, try downgrading to 1.11, `clear()` worked there pretty well.

Comment: Thanks using that function plus running the script in pieces with the help of a .bat file seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the memory with

```
ini_set("memory_limit","LIMIT");
```

for example to

```
ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
```

btw, check out: [PHP Simple HTML Dom Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304301/php-simple-html-dom-memory-issue)